# calling a method inside someClass from AppDelegate Objective-C IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to call a method that's inside someClass from the AppDelegate class.
I usually create an instance and then using that instance, call the method. Like so:

```
FFAppDelegate *delegate = (FFAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate someMethod];
```

I use that ^^ quite a bit in my code and it works perfectly. What I want to do, is switch it around. Instead of calling a method INSIDE the AppDelegate, I want to call a method inside another class FROM the AppDelegate.

```
SomeClass *test = (SomeClass *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[test someMethod];
```

In this case, I keep getting "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'" error due to "unrecognized selector sent to instance".

Any light shed on the matter would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: SomeClass is not the app delegate, so why are you instantiating an instance of SomeClass with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]? You need to get a reference to a SomeClass instance -- how you do that depends on whether you're creating that instance in the app delegate, or in a storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate an instance of the class that you want to send the request from and make the method public (in the .h file).  Then import that class into the app delegate and call it.

Like so...

```
  YourClass * yourClassInstance = [[YourClass alloc] init];
  [yourClassInstance someMethod];
```

in YourClass.h below the @interface you would declare the method like so

```
 -(void)someMethod;
```

So anyone could access it.

Comment: This seemed to work, although I have no idea why.

I had the declaration in the interface. The only thing that has changed is the [[YourClass alloc] init]; instead of my [UIApplication sharedApplication].

Thanks again.

Comment: It works because the AppDelegate doesn't declare the method and doesn't implement it.  Thus you are asking the AppDelegate (what you get from the singleton returned from [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) for its implementation and there is nothing there.  In the case I am giving you, you are getting an instance of a class which does implement the method you are asking of it, so it works.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` return your `AppDelegate` class , not `SomeClass`

you can use like this :

```
FFAppDelegate *delegate = (FFAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate someMethodForSomeClass];
```

And then in your AppDelegate code `someMethodForSomeClass` like this :

```
- (void)someMethodForSomeClass
{
    SomeClass *someClass = _yourSomeClass;
    [someClass someMethod];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Example if you want to Create AlertView only Once and Use it in any UiViewController**

**So, you can make Method For UIAlertView and Call the Method When you Want**

**1)In your appDelegate.h file**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIAlertView *activeAlertView;
```

**2) In your AppDelegate.m File**

```
-(void)openAlert
{
    NSString *strMsgPurchase = @"Write your message";
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Buy" message:strMsgPurchase delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Buy",@"Restore", nil];
    [alert setTag:100];
    [alert show];
    self.activeAlertView = alert;
}
```

**3) To Call the Method in which uiview you want**

```
[((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])openAlert];
```

Note: Define **-(void)openAlert** Method in Appdelegate.h file