# Having trouble calling objective-c method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to run a method multiple times throughout my application, but I do not want to have to duplicate the code inside the method everywhere that I need it to run. It would be much better for me to just call the existing method.

someName.h

```
@interface someName : NSObject
{
IBOutlet NSButton * button;
}
- (IBAction)methodOne:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)methodTwo:(id)sender;
@end
```

This isn't my actual header file, but this is sufficient to communicate the problem that I am having. I need to make methodOne run from inside methodTwo.

someName.m

```
@implementation someName
- (IBAction)methodOne:(id)sender
{
    //some code
}
- (IBAction)methodTwo:(id)sender
{
    //what do I put here to run methodOne again?
}
@end
```

I have tried [someName methodOne] and [[self class] methodOne] but neither one works. I am new to Cocoa and Objective-C so bear with me if I'm missing something simple.

Comment: methodOne != methodOne:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)methodTwo:(id)sender
{
//additional implementation here
    [self methodOne:sender];
}
```

will work.

Comment: Awesome! I've been trying to figure this out for days. Would you happen to know how to call methodOne from within AppDelegate.m? I've imported someName.h in appDelegate.h already, just can't figure out the syntax once again :\

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583859/calling-a-method-inside-someclass-from-appdelegate-objective-c-ios) but probably your practice is not good.