# Calling method from AppDelegate unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: objective-c, appdelegate

I'm trying to call another class's method in AppDelegate.m. I've done the following:

1. In MyClass.h, I have  `-void testMethod`
2. In AppDelegate.m, I have
   `#import "MyClass.h"`
   `MyClass * myClassInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];`
   `[myClassInstance testMethod]`
3. In AppDelegate.h, I have also imported
   `#import "MyClass.h"`

I think I've done everything the answer to this question suggested: [calling a method inside someClass from AppDelegate Objective-C IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583859/calling-a-method-inside-someclass-from-appdelegate-objective-c-ios?newreg=00ceabfc19eb42a5b0e30e4168693b4c)

But I'm still getting a "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" error?

What's missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update your question with the complete and exact error message. You've left out the import part of the message. Update your question with the exact line of code causing the error.

Comment: Did you forget to add parenthesis around void? For example, 
- (void) testMethod

Comment: @Ke Cheng you need to implement this method in m file. Check this tutorial http://roadfiresoftware.com/2014/06/how-to-implement-methods-in-objective-c/

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the method call in some appDelegate lifecycle method like:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

     // Override point for customization after application launch.    
     Test* testObject = [[Test alloc] init];
     [testObject testMethod];  
     return YES;
 }
```

For the class that you are instantiating use something like:

Test.h file

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface Test : NSObject

 -(void)testMethod;

 @end
```

and Test.m file

```
 #import "Test.h"

 @implementation Test


 -(void)testMethod{
     NSLog(@"test");
 }

 @end
```

In this case when the apps initialize the log message appears on console.